# What is the point of the re-sampling step in a particle filter?

Tags: stochastic-processes, filter, particle-filter

My general understanding of particle filters is that you represent your state as a collection of discrete particles which you then transform using your state propagation equation.

What I don't understand is why you re-sample the particles after propagation? Isn't the whole point to accurately track the distribution?

Secondly how is this fundamentally different than fitting a gaussian mixture distribution to the propagated particles and then re-sampling?

Answer (score 1):

If you had perfect knowledge of the state and the propagation equations, you wouldn't need to resample. You would already indeed be accurately tracking the distribution already.

Typically, though, you don't know the state perfectly and your propagation equations are approximations and/or they are intrinsically stochastic.  Your particles will (slowly or rapidly) diverge from each other and from the true path of the state.  Your updated estimate will be imprecise (because it's based on old data) and/or incorrect (because the propagation equations aren't perfectly correct)

When you acquire more data, you have a chance to fix this divergence. You'd like to keep the particles whose state is more consistent with the data you acquire at a later time and discard those that are less consistent with later data. Resampling does this, but in a smoother way -- it's not an in or out decision, the sampling is proportional to the likelihood given the observed data.

Comment: Could you direct me to more info on the re-sampling step? I understand that the sensor updates the state information but I haven't found a course source on how the resampling integrates that. I under the EKF framework pretty well.